# Connecting App Engine to Cloud SQL Access Denied

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to get my Flask App Engine project to read data stored in Cloud SQL MySQL 5.7 database. Something has gone wrong as all I've gotten are `pymysql.err.OperationalError`. I've been following the instructions here: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-app-engine.

1. The Cloud SQL Admin API is enabled.
2. According to the linked document:

   > App Engine uses a service account to authorize your connections to Cloud SQL. This service account must have the correct IAM permissions to successfully connect. Unless otherwise configured, the default service account is in the format service-PROJECT_NUMBER@gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

The IAM page listing the permissions for my project doesn't contain a member in the above format. The "App Engine default service account" is of the format: my-project-name@appspot.gserviceaccount.com. This service account has Cloud SQL Client and Editor roles.

3. While my queries are unsuccessful, after each attempt I note in the Logs Viewer:
   `7183 [Note] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'cloudsqlproxy~xxx.xxx.xx.xx' (using password: YES)`
   (IP address redacted). This is somewhat confusing as 'www-data' isn't a user I specified in my code.
4. The code used to connect:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://' + ':' + db_user + '@/' + db_name + '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/' + connection_name
```

Where have I gone wrong and how might I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a mySQL error when trying to connect to a database with wrong credentials.

Please verify that the values you are using are the right ones.

If you dont rember the database username and password you can change it on the console by following the next steps which are also expalined [here](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/create-manage-users#changing_a_user_password)

> - Go to [CloudSQL console](https://console.cloud.google.com/sql/instances?_ga=2.39486688.290566479.1581640383-950894874.1581640383)
> - Select your database
> - Go to users
> - next to the user select click on the three dots
> - And select Change password
> - Type the new password and click OK

Comment: Your first sentence nailed it! In this circumstance there was an error connecting to the database as the connection string was incorrectly formed. Contrast: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://' + ':' + db_user + '@/' + db_name + '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/' + connection_name` with: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql+pymysql://' + db_user + ':' + db_pass + '@/' + db_name + '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/' + connection_name`.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly likely, you're building and testing your app locally where you're supplying your credentials with a username that has access to Cloud SQL. Upon build, unless you otherwise specify, a default username will be assigned to the app engine instance.

**To fix this:**

1. Head over to *IAM & admin*
2. Search for the app engine account --> ending with `gae-api-prod.google.com.iam.gserviceaccount.com`
3. Edit
4. Assign permission *Cloud SQL Client*

---

*Let me know if this solves it for you!*